# Do I have to avoid a native sql at spring data?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have this repository:

```
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Long> {
    Message findById(long id);

    @Query(value = "SELECT * from message where sent = false and expire <= current_timestamp ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Message> findAllReadyMessages();
}
```

Would it be a good idea to avoid using native `SQL` and push new date every time ? For example:

```
List<Message> findAllBySentForProcessingFalseAndExpireIsLessThanEqual(Date expire);
```

What are benifits and drawbacks ?

Comment: Can't answer on which is better between native query and passing the Date, but I would pass a `Date` object. Once I worked in a project where the database was on a server with a different timezone than the server where the java app was hosted. So we couldn't use `current_timestamp` otherwise it would have been an issue. So I always recommend to let the app handle dates to avoid such issues.

Comment: @BackSlash Why didn't you just configure the database to work in the correct timezone?

Comment: @Kayaman Because we couldn't. The database was shared between two other applications and reconfiguring it would have required to partially rewrite two applications.

Comment: @BackSlash That just makes it a workaround. You can also handle timestamp creations in the database itself in many cases, so the actual timezone won't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option is both more readable and secure in that you can't pass a wrong date by accident.

The second option doesn't explain anything about what you're trying to achieve, and allows you to specify the parameter yourself. It's not the same query as the first one in a logical sense.

IMHO you don't have to avoid anything that gives you a good, clean solution, unless you work in a bureaucratic environment that gives you a set of silly rules you need to obey.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to pass `Date` object every time you call your repository method you can simply use a predefined `JPA` method [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/date#Current_Date_and_Time_).

Try this

```
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT m from Message m where m.sent = false and m.expire <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ")
    List<Message> findAllReadyMessages();

}
```

Comment: Yeah. I just wanted to add if you only want to do it the JPA way. Anyway thanks.